# Im getting this in spyder: AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'subs'

Tags: python, python-2.7, sympy, attributeerror

To be precise the error is:

```
x2new= solve(n.subs(x1,0).subs(x3,0))
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'subs'
```

And here's my code:

```
from sympy import symbols, Eq, solve, sympify

x, y, z= symbols('x y z')

a= 6*x - 2*y + z - 11
b= -2*x + 7 *y + 2*z - 5
c= x + 2*y - 5*z + 1

m=Eq(sympify(a))
n=Eq(sympify(b))
o=Eq(sympify(c))

x1=solve(m.subs(y,0).subs(z,0))
x2=solve(n.subs(x,0).subs(z,0))
x3=solve(o.subs(x,0).subs(y,0))

n= 2
for i in range(n):
    x1new= solve(m.subs(x2,0).subs(x3,0))
    x2new= solve(n.subs(x1,0).subs(x3,0))
    x3new= solve(o.subs(x1,0).subs(x2,0))
    
    x1= x1new
    x2= x2new
    x3= x3new
    i= i+1
    
    print(x1new)
    print(x2new)
    print(x3new)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It complains because it expects `SymPy` numbers and not the built-in python `int`.

If you take a closer look at your code, you'll notice that you are accidentally overwriting variable `n`:

```
n=Eq(sympify(b))
n= 2
```

---

If you just rename your for loop counter variable it will work just fine:

```
from sympy import symbols, Eq, solve, sympify, Integer

x, y, z= symbols('x y z')

a= 6*x - 2*y + z - 11
b= -2*x + 7 *y + 2*z - 5
c= x + 2*y - 5*z + 1

m=Eq(sympify(a), 0)
n=Eq(sympify(b), 0)
o=Eq(sympify(c), 0)

x1=solve(m.subs(y,0).subs(z,0))
x2=solve(n.subs(x,0).subs(z,0))
x3=solve(o.subs(x,0).subs(y,0))

counter = 2
for i in range(counter):
    x1new= solve(m.subs(x2,0).subs(x3,0))
    x2new= solve(n.subs(x1,0).subs(x3,0))
    x3new= solve(o.subs(x1,0).subs(x2,0))
    
    x1= x1new
    x2= x2new
    x3= x3new
    i= i+1
    
    print(x1new)
    print(x2new)
    print(x3new)
```

and the output would be:

```
[{x: y/3 - z/6 + 11/6}]
[{x: 7*y/2 + z - 5/2}]
[{x: -2*y + 5*z - 1}]
[{x: y/3 - z/6 + 11/6}]
[{x: 7*y/2 + z - 5/2}]
[{x: -2*y + 5*z - 1}]
```

Comment: I completely missed that. It is working now!